# Background resizes with page

Tags: html, css, image, background

(Please be kind I'm fairly new to all this).
I've tried using cover, absolute, auto and whatever else to try and get the background to resize along with the page. Whenever I make the resize the page smaller or bigger, I'm left with a white box at the bottom:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLNMX.jpg

The only way to get the white to go away is if I make the page full size again. Here's my CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  background-image:url("https://66.media.tumblr.com/6c5a2aeca064c07feb499ace6b3cd205/87a13546c57cc3af-65/s1280x1920/7f41aeae69f0fac081602c946f5aa9e5c5077c94.jpg"); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-positon: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
</style>
<title>home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/">
<link rel="icon" href="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f9/8f/c3/f98fc32fb656fe36088b94f789019adb.png">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The background does scale with screen size , i don't see the problem

Comment: do you want cover full of page ? or want cover mode

Answer (score 1):

try fix this issues :

- add `;` after **width: 100%**
- this property value **absolute** not correct `background-positon: absolute;`

check this link to know the correct value

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

- you have also a typo on `positon` should be `background-position:`

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code for cover for background of page but you must keep your ratio aspect for picture 
your code have two error 
1- `background-position:absolute` is wrong 
2-`width:100%` it is not correct because  body have this properties
then you must change your code like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
html,body{
 height:100%;
}
body {
  background-image:url("https://66.media.tumblr.com/6c5a2aeca064c07feb499ace6b3cd205/87a13546c57cc3af-65/s1280x1920/7f41aeae69f0fac081602c946f5aa9e5c5077c94.jpg"); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
 }
</style>
<title>home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/">
<link rel="icon" href="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f9/8f/c3/f98fc32fb656fe36088b94f789019adb.png">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```